# Как определить, скрывается или появляется в данный момент div?

Tags: jquery

Можно определить, скрыт ли объект в данный момент:

```
if ($('div').is(':visible')) {...
```

Можно определить, анимируется ли объект:

```
if ($('div').is(':animated')) {...
```

Но если мы запустили, например, `fadeToggle`, как определить скрывается объект или, наоборот, появляется?

По идее, объект всегда будет видимым и анимированным, это никак не говорит о том, скрывается он или появляется.

Пример, когда мы просто определяем анимацию, предлагаю дополнить его:

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('#div').fadeToggle(1000);
})
$('#testanim').click(function() {
  if ($('#div').is(':animated')) {
    console.log('объект анимируется')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='toggle'>Toggle</button>
<button id='testanim'>Тест animated</button>

<div id=div>test</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через искусственное состояние с помощью функции `prop`:

```js
$('*').prop('fadeToggleStatus', 1); // Применяем ко всем элементам

$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('#div').fadeToggle(1000);
  if($('#div').prop('fadeToggleStatus') == 1){
    $('#div').prop('fadeToggleStatus', 0);
  }else{
    $('#div').prop('fadeToggleStatus', 1);
  };
});
$('#testanim').click(function() {
  if($('#div').prop('fadeToggleStatus') == 1) {
    console.log('Открывается!')
  }else{
    console.log('Закрывается!')
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='toggle'>Toggle</button>
<button id='testanim'>Тест на событие</button>

<div id=div>test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте callback.
Сделайте переменную stateAnimate.

```
stateAnimate = true;
fadeToggle(1000, function(){
   stateAnimate = false;
});
```